# iMessage deletion when not on Wi-Fi

Tags: messages, data-synchronization

Someone sent me an embarrassing picture on my iPhone, which is synced to my iPad for iMessage.

My iPad was not connected to Wi-Fi at that point.

I then deleted the embarrassing picture from my iPhone, before the iPad was connected to Wi-Fi.

So, when the iPad is finally connected to Wi-Fi, will the picture come through onto that device, despite it having been previously deleted on my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Your iPad will mirror your iPhone (because the iPhone picked-up the message first).

The pic should not display on the iPad as long as it's not in the message history on your iPhone.